# Unable to change image when clicking on button using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, raspberry-pi3, gpio

I am developing web controlled Home Automation using Raspberry Pi. I referred the following the link
https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/iot-raspberry-pi-home-automation

But I am customizing HTML, CSS page. I have developed HTML page as follows

```
<body>
    <h1 align=center>Web Based Controlled Home Automation using Raspberry Pi </h1>

    <div id="content" align="center"></div>
    <center><img src="/img/roomlighton.jpeg" height="500px" width="800px" id='pic1' /></center>
    <br / >
```

I write script (.js ) and stylesheet for same (.css)
My .js file as follows

```
webiopi().ready(function() {
            webiopi().setFunction(4,"out");
            //webiopi().setFunction(18,"out");
            //webiopi().setFunction(22,"out");
            //webiopi().setFunction(23,"out");


            var content, button;
            content = $("#content");

            button = webiopi().createGPIOButton(4,"Room 1");
            content.append(button);

        /* $('content').click(function(){
                         $('#pic1').attr('src','/img/roomlightoff.png');
        });
        */
```

My css file is as follows

```
button {
                    display: block;
                    position: absolute;
                    margin: 40px 610px;
                    padding: 0 10px;
                    text-align: center;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    width: 130px;
                    height: 40px;
                    font: bold 18px/25px Arial, sans-serif;                 
                    color: black;


                text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .22);
                -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
                -moz-border-radius: 30px;
                border-radius: 30px;

                -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .29), inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .44);
                -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .29), inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .44);
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .29), inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .44);

                -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease;
                -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease;
                -o-transition: all 0.15s ease;
                -ms-transition: all 0.15s ease;
                transition: all 0.15s ease;
        }

#gpio4.LOW {
                    background-color: Gray;
                    color: Black;
                    // background-image:url('/img/roomlightoff.png');
            }

            #gpio4.HIGH {
                    background-color: Red;
                    color: LightGray;
            }
```

it's working fine. Currently, when I clicked on button (#gpio.HIGH / # gpio.LOW) background color changes accordingly. But the problem is that I also want to change image source simultaneously. When I click the button, I want to change `background-image` source at the same time. Right now, the page displays a constant image.

I tried `background-image:url('/img/roomlightoff.png');` 
but its not working , it changes background-image of button,not page.

please help to solve this.

Comment: can you add your javascript to the question?

Comment: Try changing "$('content').click ...." to "$(button).click ...." in your js.

Comment: i changed to $("button"),it works.but it changes image permanently. I want that, when button click(#GPIO4.HIGH) it displays one image(eg.lighton.jpg") while when button click(#GPIO4.LOW) it displays another image(eg. lightoff.jpg). Currently when I load page,it displays lighton.jpg image and when I click button it replaces lightoff.jpg image permanently.